# Story about a mean empath who helps people for an atypical reason

Tags: story-identification

I'm not sure if I **read** it, or I **read a story where a character referenced it**, but there is a character who is a very strong empath (actual paranormal or psychic ability, not just 'empathic' in a more standard sense), and not a nice person, but spends his life helping people, not out of any altruistic motives, but so they will stop radiating their misery into his head.

My GUESS would be that it's from, or was referenced in, a **Spider Robinson** book, but I don't seem to be able to find it.  I read Spider from about 1992 to, well, now, so it could be anywhere in that range.

Comment: I mean, helping someone just so they shut up for a few minutes?  That's not _that_ rare. :D

Comment: If it was read in the past decade, perhaps one of Ted Chiang's short stories?

Answer (score 3):

If it is Spider Robinson, it could be one of the Russell Walker duology-Very Bad Deaths or Very Hard Choices. They were published in 2004 and 2008 respectively.  In the first book, they meet as room-mates in college; the empath deliberately keeps himself dirty and smelly, so that people stay away from him. https://www.fantasticfiction.com/r/spider-robinson/russell-walker/

Comment: I'll find my copy and take a look, verify if it's it, and then circle back to accept if it is the one -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might be "Need" by Theodore Sturgeon.  I had occasion to review it briefly once and wrote in part:

> The substance of the story is mainstream Sturgeon, with a cast of sensitive misfits plus a crass and insensitive slug in urgent need of an education about life, the whole about as didactic as Ayn Rand though considerably more readable. Sturgeon never did quite catch on to “show, don’t tell.” The main misfit is someone who perceives need and has to do something about it, though that doesn’t make him particularly nice. He responds to a hitchhiking drug addict by running him out of town. The real hero is an eccentric but (of course) very wise junk shop owner who permits Sturgeon to indulge his preoccupation with tools and gadgets and how to use them. And if my comment sounds overly cranky, again: it’s not a bad story, it’s just a reminder of how much better Sturgeon could have been.

This story first appeared in Sturgeon's 1960 collection BEYOND, and has been reprinted in a Spider Robinson anthology, THE BEST OF ALL POSSIBLE WORLDS (1980) and in THE MAN WHO LOST THE SEA, vol. X in Sturgeon's COMPLETE STORIES.

Comment: A distinct possibility; Spider does reference Sturgeon in a number of stories; I'll dig up a copy and come back once I have more info -- thanks!